# Prove the convergence of the geometric series using $\epsilon$, N definition

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Show $| \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n - \frac{1}{1-x} | < \epsilon$ using the definition of convergence when |x|< 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will begin from where you left in your comment above.

I hope you know that if $|x| < 1$, then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x^{n} = 0$ and hence, given $\epsilon > 0, \, \exists n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq n_{0} \Rightarrow |x^{n}| < \epsilon(1 - |x|)$. Note that $(1 - |x|)$ is a constant.

Now this is your required $n_{0}$.

Let me know if you need further clarifications.

Comment: so my n would be: $$n < \frac{ln(\epsilon(1-|x|)}{ln(|x|)} $$

Comment: You do not need to calculate your $n$ explicitly. The fact that such a $n$ exists is sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: Forgive this question as I am not very familiar with analysis but is an $\epsilon, \delta$ approach a different from above? The original question reads give an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}, $$ when |x| < 1.

Comment: What I gave is the proof you need. Your approach is alright too but the only thing is that you do not have to calculate $n$ explicitly, although it does no harm to do so.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Note that when $|x|<1$, $$\frac{x^{m}}{1-x}\to 0$$

Now, what is $$1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{m-1}?$$ And what happens when you subtract $(1-x)^{-1}$ from that?

Comment: This was my attempt at a solution: I know that for an infinite series the series will converge is its partial sum converges. The partial sum is 
$$ S = \sum_{n=0}^N x^n = \frac{1-x^{N+1}}{1-x}, $$ so this reduces to 
$$| \frac{x^{N+1}}{1-x} | \leq \frac{|x|^{N+1}}{1-|x|}. $$ 
Let $\epsilon > 0$ and let N be the smallest n$\in\mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$ \frac{|x|^{N+1}}{1-|x|} < \epsilon. $$ 
$$ N > \frac{\ln(\epsilon(1-|x|))}{ln(|x|)} - 1. $$ I feel like something is missing.

Comment: The $(1-|x|)$ term is irrelevant, don't worry about it. Can you show that for any $x$ with $|x|<1$, $|x|^n\to 0$? For example, this is a decreasing sequence bounded below, hence the limit exists. What should that limit be?

Comment: I can certainly see that if $|x|$< 1, Then $|x|^n$ will become a sequence where the denominator will eventually dominates the numerator and the limit will become zero.

Comment: Isn't it $log_x$, not $ln$?

Answer (score 0):

So my take on this is let $S = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r^n$. Then the partial sum $s_n = a+ar+...+ar^n$. Notice $s_n-rs_n=1-r^{n+1}$. So $s_n(1-r)=1-r^{n+1} \implies s_n = \frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$. So now we show that the sequence of the partial sums $s_n$ converges to $\frac{a}{1-r}$.
\begin{align}
|\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}-\frac{1}{1-r}| &= |\frac{-(r)^{n+1}}{1-r}| \\
&\leq \frac{|r|^{n+1}}{1-|r|} 
< \epsilon
\end{align}

So $n < \log_r(\epsilon(1-|r|))-1$

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $N = \lceil{\log_r(\epsilon(1-|r|))-1}\rceil$ so that if $n > N \geq \log_r(\epsilon(1-|r|))-1$ we have:

$|s_n-\frac{1}{1-r}| = |\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}-\frac{1}{1-r}| = \frac{r^{n+1}}{1-|r|} < \epsilon$.

And then by definition, the original series $S = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r^n$ converges to $\frac{1}{1-r}$.

I feel like I have a lot of errors regarding absolute values and the inequality signs in my steps. Any feedback will be useful. Thank you.