# Prove/disprove sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $a_n := \sum_{k=1}^n b^{-k}$ converges for $b > 1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Let $b > 1$. Then, the sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $a_n := \sum_{k=1}^n b^{-k}$ converges.

I would argue that this is true because we can rewrite $a_n$ as $a_n := \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{b^k}$ which converges to $0$ for $\lim{k \to \infty}$.

Is that correct or what would be a more formal way to prove this?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Cf. [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Comment: “$a_n := \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{b^k}$ which converges to $0$ for $\lim{k \to \infty}$” sorry, what?! What does that even mean? The limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{b^k}$ is definitely not zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claiming a convergence to zero (of, I assume, the terms) here doesn't mean anything. Just because $\sum s_n$ has $s_n \to 0$ doesn't mean anything. The cases of

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 n \qquad \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$$

both have their summands tending to zero, but the former diverges ([proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Harmonic_Series_is_Divergent)) and the latter is known to converge to $\pi^2/6$ (various proofs [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Category:Basel_Problem)).

Termwise convergence to zero is **necessary** but it's not **sufficient** -- you need more.

---

Now, you do hit on a certain point. Since $b>1$, then $0 < 1/b < 1$, and

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{b} \right)^n$$

is a geometric series, known to converge to

$$\frac{1/b}{1-1/b}; \text{ that is, } \frac{1}{b-1}$$

---

If you want to *formally* prove that $a_n := \sum_{k=1}^n (1/b)^k$  converges to this, you'll need an $\varepsilon-N$ proof: show that, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, we can find an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, whenever $n \ge N$,

$$\left| \frac{1}{b-1} - \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \frac{1}{b} \right)^n \right| < \varepsilon$$

Some ideas on the matter can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483522/prove-the-convergence-of-the-geometric-series-using-epsilon-n-definition) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807592/epsilon-delta-proof-of-geometric-series-x1).